# Setters are called twice in JSF managed bean

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having an issue applying dates to my managedBean since I added jquerys datePicker to an application.

I attach the datepicker to the two date fields and it is working fine(It pops up and allow selection of  dates, the input field changes to reflect date selections correctly).

myBean.java

```
public class MyBean {

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public MyBean()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void filterList()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Date getStartDate()
    {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate)
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate()
    {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date startDate)
    {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

myPage.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="my_requests_pending">
    <rich:panel id="filter_panel">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.filter}">
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText id="startDateLbl" value="#{messages['MyBeanMessages.startDate']}" />
                <h:panelGrid>                       
                    <h:inputText id="startDate" value="#{mysBean.startDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="E, d MMM, yyyy" timeZone="#{localeBean.timeZone}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText value="#{messages['MyBeanMessages.endDate']}" />
                <h:panelGrid> 
                    <h:inputText id="endDate" value="#{myBean.endDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="E, d MMM, yyyy" timeZone="#{localeBean.timeZone}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:commandButton id="myReqSubmitBtn" value="#{messages['MyBeanMessages.submit']}" action="#{myBean.filterList}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

myCalendar.js

```
jQuery('startDate,endDate').datepicker.({
        showOn : 'both',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        showOtherMonths : true,
        selectOtherMonths : true,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        dateFormat : "D, d M, yy",
        showAnim : "slideDown"
    });
```

A problem occurs when I **submit** my form. 
The setStartDate/setEndDate methods are getting called twice (I can see this in debug mode).
The first time sets the date correctly to the new changed date and the second call is resetting it back to the origional date.

Is their something going on with the JSF lifecycle that I'm not aware of?
Any help appreciated.

### UPDATE

The problem seems to be on the 'Update Model' JSF phase.
It outputs the following debug code:

```
09-Nov-2011 16:02:26 org.exadel.jsf.PhaseTracker beforePhase
INFO: BEFORE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
```

- It then hits the breakpoint in setStartDate() method and updates the startDate property correctly.
- When it leaves the setStartDate() Method it then make numerous calls to jsf libraries, etc...and returns again to my breakpoint in setStartDate()!
- I then step out of the method and following debug code appears.

> ```
> 09-Nov-2011 17:06:21 org.exadel.jsf.PhaseTracker afterPhase
> INFO: AFTER UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
> 09-Nov-2011 17:06:21 org.exadel.jsf.PhaseTracker beforePhase
> INFO: BEFORE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
> ```

Comment: So, if you remove `datePicker`, it works as expected? That's plain odd. Can you tell during which JSF phase the methods are called and if it's really within the same HTTP request? Isn't there actually something more into the form which you omitted for brevity?

Comment: Yes, I removed the datepicker event listener and simply changed the dates manually, it submits fine this way. Check my question for an update on JSF phase causing the problem.

Comment: This is plain odd. Doesn't the `datePicker` script add another hidden input field with the **same name** or something? Use Firebug's or Chrome's "Inspect Element" to figure it.

Comment: This problem made me curious enough that I will test it with jQuery UI DatePicker myself sooner or later, but I'd like to know first what JSF impl/version and RF version you're using. By the way, is there any particular reason that you don't just use RichFaces' own `<rich:calendar>`?

Comment: Not at work now so I can't respond with full details. I'm using JSF2 with Richfaces 3.3. I'm not using the Richfaces calendar as it does not provide a simple way to have separate drop-downs for month and year in the header (Lots of business sign-off circles to go through if I changed it to use Richfaces way of selecting the months/years).
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: I'll check for the hidden fields tomorrow. Thanks for help so far balasC.

Comment: Ok, found the root of the problem and it's something simple! I had extra hidden inputs on the form but removed them for brevity and you earlier started. See answer. datePicker does not appear to add any of it's own hidden fields by the way.

Comment: You should have mentioned that sooner... You didn't give any respons on that question in my first comment, so I assumed that this is not the case.

Comment: Yeah my bad, missed it somehow..sorry BalusC. Hopefully you wont ignore any future questions I post! :(

Comment: Oh no, I won't :) Human mistakes are forgiveable, idiocy not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following code in my form also (Legacy code from previous calendars functionality).

```
<h:panelGrid id="hiddendates" styleClass="panelgrid-nopad"
                style="display:none">
                <h:outputText id="formId" value="#{formId}" />
                <h:inputText id="startDateHidden"
                    value="#{myRequestsBean.startDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        timeZone="#{localeBean.timeZone}" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:inputText id="endDateHidden" value="#{myRequestsBean.endDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        timeZone="#{localeBean.timeZone}" />
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

These fields have id's of 'startDateHidden' and 'endDateHidden'.
Are the fields mapped to setters/getters based on the el value? (And not the actual id of the field).

Comment: Ids are used for mapping between html and server-side component while value EL determines for which object getter/setter will be called by the component.